# Delete first array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an php array`$a` which outputs:-

```
Array ( [0] => 47 ) Array ( [0] => 47 [1] => 51 )
```

How do i make it output like this:-

```
Array ( [0] => 47 [1] => 51 )
```

So that first array gets deleted.

**There are two Arrays in one variable**

Comment: `unset($a[0])`?

Comment: @nick `unset($a[0])` removes both 47

Comment: `array_unique(array_merge([47],[47,51]));`

Comment: @Noman I need to work with variables

Comment: @JeffB  `$a = [47]; $b = [47,51]; var_dump(array_unique(array_merge($a,$b)));`

Comment: "I have an php array `$a` which outputs" It rather looks like you have two PHP arrays. Are you in a loop or something?

Comment: @Noman Its good but as shown in question, two array is in one variable.

Comment: Your output isn't really clear @JeffB

Comment: `$a = [47];$b = [47,51];$result = array_unique(array_merge($a,$b));var_dump($result);`

Comment: Man two arrays are there in one variable

Comment: @JeffB Please check edit 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason why you would get such an output is because you print_r inside the loop.

I believe you have something like:

```
$aa = [47, 51];

foreach($aa as $a){
    $b[] = $a;
    print_r($b);
}

/*Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 47
)
Array
(
    [0] => 47
    [1] => 51
)*/
```

But instead you should have done this:

```
$aa = [47, 51];

foreach($aa as $a){
    $b[] = $a;
}
print_r($b);

/*Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 47
    [1] => 51
)
```

Here you can see the difference.

First two outputs are from inside the loop, the last is after the loop.

https://3v4l.org/kln74

I.e. your code is correct but the output is placed wrong and therefore confusing you to believe there is two items with key 0 and value 47.

Answer (score 1):

Two arrays in one variable - impossible.
If you see two arrays in output than you outputs $a variable two times.

Answer to the question "Delete first array php" you can use array_shift() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

```
array_shift($a);
```

Comment: This answer is actually correct but it's a bit unclear and written more like a comment. Vitalijs if you add some code example to your answer maybe it will be more clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

From Comments:

> @Noman Its good but as shown in question, two array is in one
>   variable.

It seems you require below solution.

Let assume you have two different arrays (**$a** and **$b**) but have same value for any element in the array. e.g: 47 is present in both arrays.

so you need to merge both array into one using **array_merge** and add **array_unique** to to filter out unique values.

```
$a = [47]; 
$b = [47,51];
$merge = array_merge($a,$b); // array(3) { [0]=> int(47) [1]=> int(47) [2]=> int(51) }
$unique = array_unique($merge); 
var_dump($unique); // array(2) { [0]=> int(47) [2]=> int(51) }
```

This will output unique values removing duplicate value.

> Note: This solution will remove any duplicate value from resultant
>   array.

**EDIT 2**

```
$a = [[47], [47, 51]];

function array_flatten($array)
{
    if (!is_array($array)) return FALSE;
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value))
            $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value));
        else $result[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $result;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_unique(array_flatten($a)));
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
Array([0] => 47  [2] => 51)
```

[**See Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0296ef1543df3da86266dcd7d555ef4494d45615) click on "Execute Code"

Comment: he want only the first element to be deleted but you could delete another entry too with this code

Comment: he assuming the first element to be delete for now. if you can see his reply in comments. `@Noman Its good but as shown in question, two array is in one variable.`

Comment: Two arrays in one variable not two variables